# I cannot get this fixed and tried the apt --fix-broken install also

Tags: apt

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-generic : Depends: linux-headers-4.15.0-169-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-169-generic but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-169-generic but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed
 ubuntu-advantage-tools : Depends: distro-info (>= 0.18ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
.. install failed!
```

When I ran the `apt --fix-broken install`:

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apt-show-versions libapt-pkg-perl linux-headers-4.15.0-117
  linux-headers-4.15.0-117-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-123
  linux-headers-4.15.0-123-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-128
  linux-headers-4.15.0-128-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-136
  linux-headers-4.15.0-136-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-142
  linux-headers-4.15.0-142-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-143
  linux-headers-4.15.0-143-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-144
  linux-headers-4.15.0-144-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-154
  linux-headers-4.15.0-154-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-45
  linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-50
  linux-headers-4.15.0-50-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-65
  linux-headers-4.15.0-65-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-74
  linux-headers-4.15.0-74-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-99
  linux-headers-4.15.0-99-generic linux-image-4.15.0-117-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-123-generic linux-image-4.15.0-128-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-136-generic linux-image-4.15.0-142-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-143-generic linux-image-4.15.0-144-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-154-generic linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-50-generic linux-image-4.15.0-65-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-74-generic linux-image-4.15.0-99-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-117-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-123-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-128-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-136-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-142-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-143-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-144-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-154-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-45-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-50-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-65-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-74-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-99-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-117-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-123-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-128-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-136-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-142-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-143-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-144-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-154-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-45-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-50-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-65-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-74-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-99-generic
  php python-pyicu
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnss-systemd libpam-systemd systemd
Suggested packages:
  systemd-container
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libnss-systemd libpam-systemd systemd
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 80 not upgraded.
Need to get 3128 kB of archives.
```

Based on response (thank you for responding):

Did that above (first one) and got this:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
Hit:1 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:6 http://software.virtualmin.com/vm/6/gpl/apt virtualmin-bionic InRelease
Hit:7 http://software.virtualmin.com/vm/6/gpl/apt virtualmin-universal InRelease
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
83 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 systemd : Depends: libsystemd0 (= 237-3ubuntu10.52) but 237-3ubuntu10.53 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: "Correcting dependencies... Done" means exactly that, the problem was corrected. You may want to run `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` to make sure your system is fully updated and then run `sudo apt autoremove` to clean up.

Comment: Well the response I got back to this was:

Comment: First clean-up the old kernels and all: `sudo apt autoremove`then run the same command again. If the same error try `sudo apt install --reinstall systemd`